# visual studio code editor not autocompleting, colour coding or giving suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

UPDATE:  I solved my own problem.  Solution is at end of this post

Original Post:

**Intro:**

Hi, I had Visual Studio Code (VSCode) installed a long time back for use with Unity but ended up not using it and opted for Visual Studio instead because that was what my Unity course was using.

I am now learning HTML so I now want to use the Visual Studio Code as the editor.

**Problem:**

When I type out my HTML code, VSCode is not autocompleting any of my code or giving me any suggestions or colour coding the text.

**Troubleshooting steps done:**

I completely uninstalled Visual Studio Code including the user data folders: .vscode in users and Code in Appdata/Romaning (which were advised on the visual Studio code website uninstall instructions).

I then installed a fresh version.  But the same problem persists.

Update:  I have learnt that the feature that I have an issue with is called Intellisense.  CTRL-SHIFT-R is supposed to refresh this feature module.  So did this and I get the message "No refactorings available".  So perhaps I am missing a module or plugin that I am supposed to also install?

I'd appreciate someone's help to solve this.

Many thanks.

PS This is my first StackOverflow question, I hope it's not a forehead slapping debut!

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

I just solved my own problem...and it's probably a beginner's mistake...

I discovered at the bottom right corner of the editor, this a menu tray.  One of these items showed "Plain Text".  On clicking it, it showed a list of programming languages.  Naturally HTML was one of them and I upon clicking it.  The editor Intellisense auto completion, suggestions etc kicked in.

If I may comment, I wonder why this element is somewhat conspicuous.  It's not obvious for a beginner to know to click on "Plain Text" at the bottom  right corner without scouring the interface or try to find a third party tutorial video.  Perhaps, I can give that as a feedback to the developers.

Comment: You should edit your question and post solution as answer.

Comment: Now the question: Why does VSC set the LanguageId of a file ending in `.html` to `Plain Text`?

Comment: @rioV8 that's a good point too.  Worthy of submitting as a feedback to the Microsoft and hopefully be implements in a future update.

Comment: It already does on my machine so something is not correct on your end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my own problem...and it's probably a beginner's mistake.

I discovered at the bottom right corner of the editor, this a menu tray.  One of these items showed "Plain Text".  On clicking it, it showed a list of programming languages.  Naturally HTML was one of them and I upon clicking it.  The editor Intellisense auto completion, suggestions etc kicked in.